# Anaconda Navigator cannot be run with root user privileges

Tags: anaconda

I am a new one to Ubuntu16.04LTS. After I install anaconda on ubuntu16.04, the problem "Anaconda Navigator cannot be run with root user privileges" occurs. (PS: I log in Ubuntu as the root user) What should i do to open the navigator? Looking for your help, thx.

Comment: What about logging in as a normal, non root, user ? Nearly no normal work needs root to run.

Comment: Cause i did not install anaconda in non-root-user accounts, I have not tried to launch anaconda-navigator as a normal user. In fact, I want to install anaconda as the root user and share the access to other normal users.

Comment: After what I can see, Anaconda can only be installed on a "per user" basis. Maybe this question is beyond the scope of this site and should be posted on a Anaconda related site.

Comment: I find a way to solve this problem(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118366/how-to-start-anaconda-navigator-with-root-privileges-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda navigator is not designing for root user but you can use Anaconda as root and share access to all users. In this case, you need to manage conda by command line and not Navigator.

For official documentation about this, read [Administering a multi-user conda installation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/admin-multi-user-install.html).

Answer (score 0):

> dont need to thanks.

`nano /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py`

ctrl+w to find `geteuid` replace with `getppid` or change value from 0 to 1

```
    if (MAC or LINUX) and os.geteuid() == 1:
```

looks like upper line.